# Trying to use application.GetOpenFilename to open an excel file inside a .zip

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing an excel macro where I want to use `application.GetOpenFilename` to open an excel file from inside a `.zip` folder. This does not work since GetOpenFilename tries to load/open the folder itself. There are multiple Excel files inside the .zip, and I am interested in a specific one which name varies from occasion to occasion. Browsing must thus be done manually.

What do I need to do in order to let the user browse for the correct file inside the .zip folder?

I have read Ron de Bruin's take on unzipping, and have not found a solution to my problem (https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s7/win002.htm).

```
Dim wb As Workbook

' Here I want the user to browse for the correct file

myFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Browse for excel file")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
```

Ideally, the solution should treat this .zip folder like any regular folder, allowing the user of my macro to browse inside this .zip for the correct excel file.

Comment: This does not work. You need to unzip a file (at least temporarily) to open it. If you plan to edit that file you need to zip it again after you saved it. You cannot use zipped files directly. Imagine a zip file like a bag for files. You need to unpack that bag before you can use the files in it.

Comment: Understood. 
Thanks